# where is the declaration of SchemaRDD in spark 1.3.0's API

Tags: scala, apache-spark

1. these code reports error in IDEA，why?

   ```
   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
   import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
   val people = sc.textFile("c3/test.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
   people.registerTempTable("people")
   ```
2. Is there another way to transform  `sqlContext` into `SchemaRDD`, excepting the `import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD`?
3. I can't find the `SchemaRDD` class in spark api document, why?

Comment: what do you mean by "transform `sqlContext` into `SchemaRDD`"...?? `sqlContext` gives you access to functionality related to `Spark-SQL`. Now out of these many functions... one is `createSechemaRDD` function which creates a returns a `SchemaRDD`.

Comment: Because `SchemaRDD` is part of `Spark-SQL` ( Originally called as Apache-Shark ) which is still separate from regular `Spark` API.

Comment: Also... the reason for error is that you have not imported the implicit type classes from `sqlContext.implicits._` which provide extra ad-hoc polymorphic functionality enriching the regular Spark data structures with Spark-SQL functionality.

Answer (score 3):

`SchemaRDD` has been renamed to `DataFrame` in Apache Spark 1.3.0. See the [migration guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#migration-guide).

Comment: and in Spark>=2.0 it has been renamed to Dataset afaik

Comment: Yes, kinda. There is still a `DataFrame` type, but it is just an alias to `Dataset[Row]`.